# How many project groups can Netbeans 8.1 support?

Tags: netbeans

I use project groups in [NetBeans 8.1](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/) to better organize my projects.

What I can't seem to find anywhere is how many project groups Netbeans supports.

Is there a set number of project groups allowed by Netbeans, or can you have as many as you want?

Comment: You should edit your question and indicate what version of Netbeans you are using.